# t-sql return a value if where in fails

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm using T-sql. I need some help with my SQL. I'm using the IN statement, as an example i look for 1,32,21 now some of the records will only have two of the numbers is there someway I could return, 'YES' if it is IN the list and 'NO' if its not and then instead count the number if 'yes'.

**UPDATE!!**

```
id  firstName   uid   value name                     amount typeofthing
161 sture       10470   1   Engineer Officer Class 1    1   certificate
444 kumba       10472   1   Engineer Officer Class 1    3   certificate
```

Here's my data! as you can see the user with **UID 10470** 
 only holds 1 certificate. What I want to achive is to have a new row to my data like this

```
id  firstName   uid   value name                     amount typeofthing HasorNot
161 sture       10470   1   Engineer Officer Class 1    1   certificate YES
161 sture       10470   32  Engineer Officer Class 2    1   certificate NO 
161 sture       10470   21  Engineer Officer Class 3    1   certificate NO
```

And that amount is counted on the amount of YES:es for each type.
I want this to get the name of the course/certificate they dont have? The SQL I use is below. Thanks

```
select  
   tuc.id, tu.firstName, tuc.uid, tuc.value, tc.name, 
   count(tuc.value) over (PARTITION BY tuc.uid) as 'amount', 'certificate' as 'typeofthing' 
from 
   t_user_certificates tuc, t_certificates tc, t_users tu 
where 
   tuc.[value] IN (1,32,21)
   AND tuc.value = tc.id
   AND tu.id = tuc.uid

union 

select 
   tuc.id, tu.firstName, tuc.uid, tuc.value, tc.name, 
   count(tuc.value) over (PARTITION BY tuc.uid) as 'amount', 
   'courses' as 'typeofthing' 
from 
   t_user_courses tuc, t_courses tc, t_users tu 
where 
   tuc.[value] IN(2,16,21) 
   AND tuc.value = tc.id
   AND tu.id = tuc.uid
```

Comment: It is not quite clear what you are after. Could you provide some example data and the expected results?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**20 years** ago!). ***Please*** stop using it

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading you right, it seems like you could have something like `CASE WHEN count(tuc.value) = 0 THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END` in your select list

Or not, after seeing the data update. I think this'll do it:

Step 1 is use an outer join between the tu and tuc tables. See @marc_s's comment.
Step 2 is get rid of the "id" column in your output, or allow it to be null. It appears that if a user doen'st have a given certificate, there will be no row in tuc, so this column doesn't make sense for all rows.
Step 3 is to add a column  `CASE WHEN tuc.value IS NULL THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES' END AS 'HasOrNot'`

Comment: How should I put that into my sql?